# how to add a new menu under the menu "help" in vscode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, menu, vscode-extensions

I need to add a new menu "First Kit" in submenu of "help" menu in vscode extension, there is my code in package.json.

```json
   "submenus": [
      {
        "id": "firstkitSubmenu",
        "label": "First Kit"
      }
    ],
    "menus": {
      "help": [
        {
          "submenu": "firstkitSubmenu",
          "group": "FirstKitGroup"
        }
      ],
      "firstkitSubmenu": [
        {
          "id": "helpdesk",
          "command": "first-kit.helpdesk",
          "title": "Helpdesk"
        },
        {
          "id": "documentation",
          "command": "first-kit.documentation",
          "title": "Documentation"
        }
      ]
    }
```

The new menu is not visible!! Currently, I am only able to add my item in the editor context menu in vs code.
How can I do that?
If not then can we add a submenu item in any of the existing menus? Like if could I add an menu item in menu bar?

Comment: where in the doc is a mention you can add menu items to the Window menu

Comment: related docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus